Van der Waals for Two Chemical Species
I have a system of chemical species undergoing several reactions very very near the equilibrium, their total concentrations change as you would expect in some sort of clock reaction. My first attempt at investigating this would be studying the system as a Van der Waals fluid, so I wanted to consult this approach with more people.
Given two chemical species $(1)$ and $(2)$, my first guess would be describing their behaviour separately by using the Van der Wals state equation for the partial pressures in the following way for each chemical species
$$p_{j}=x_{j}\Big(\frac{RT}{V_{m}-b_{mix}}-\frac{a_{j}x{j}^2+a_{kj}x_{k}}{V_{m}^2}\Big)$$
Where we'd take $p_{j}$ as the partial pressure associated to the $j$-th species,$x_{j}$ as the $j$-th partial mole fraction such that $x_{1}+x_{2}=1$ , $V_{m}=V_{1}+V_{2}$ the net molar volume of the system  $b_{mix}=x_{1}b_{1}+x_{2}b_{2}$ as the total molar volume of molecules, $a_{j}$ the self interaction term and $a_{kj}$ the cross interaction term.
My question is twofold

How do we measure the cross interaction terms in the case when $a_{jk}\neq a_{kj}$? I know that for simplicity it's usually taken as $a_{12}=a_{21}=\sqrt{a_{1}a_{2}}$ but this might not be the case here.

How is this typically extended for non equilibrium systems, for example where $a_{j},a_{kj},a_{jk}$ change over time, along with the temperatures $T_{1}$ and $T_{2}$?


For the second question, I know I could perhaps prepare a heat bath in advance, but even so, the nature of the reactions could have exothermal and endothermal properties which make temperatures vary and my end goal would be to capture the chemotaxis as faithfully as possible.

Perhaps a bit more context would be helpful, I'm trying to model the sort of free expansion for the reaction, as one chemical species turns into another and then back we've got changes in the net volume of our system with time. Since these follow periodic orbits then we're left with a dynamical system for $p_{net}$and $V_{net}$ such that
$$\dot{p}_{net}˙=f(p_{net},V_{net})$$
$$\dot{V}_{net}˙=g(p_{net},V_{net})$$
My end goal is to show that these follow closed orbits due to hopf bifurcations

Welcome to Physics.SE Jkaa_11. It would be much better if you edit your post to add the details you added here in the comments. Comments are meant only for asking for clarifications or as brief helpful remarks (by other users) about a post. The "Edit" option is just under your post -- if you can't find it you can use this link.

Ty, I've edited the original post and deleted  the comment
